# Resetting OS on each boot

Tags: windows, macos, ubuntu

Anyone know anything about resetting these 3 OS's on boot, I prefer some kind of software.

I have 3 machines that i use for testing software, i want those machince to be as clean as possible after each boot.

- Mac OS X 10.6.8
- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
- Windows 7

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.virtualbox.org/

Comment: Why the downvotes? What did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

For Windows and Linux variants the easiest way is to host them in a virtual machine. If you use VMWare then you can set the disk to be non-persistent, so that when you reboot it goes back to the last snapshot.  You can do this in the free VMWare player.

For the Mac I think you would need to set up an OSX server which can then provide [Netboot](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4178) images to client machines that reset to a known state every time.

Answer (score 0):

Virtualisation is probably the way to go with this. Use something like VirtualBox and can take a snapshot of the operating system in a fresh state.

Then, it is trivial to reset any of the OS in question to a blank state. It will also mean you won't need 3 machines anymore, you could do it with 1.

Comment: that could be a solution. But it would be awesome if some software could just delete/revert all files since login

Comment: Not sure about Linux, but Windows and Mac both have some restore features don't they? i.e. Time machine in Mac?

Comment: I have 3 machines because of different hardware (cpu speed/ram avail).

Comment: With VirtualBox you can specify the cpu and ram availability to each VM.

Comment: You know anything about using diskimages and then reinstall the image on boot?

Answer (score 0):

One option for OS X is [Faronics Deep Freeze](http://www.faronics.com/enterprise/deep-freeze/mac/), which resets the computer back to standard at each reboot. It's not going to be as convenient or flexible as a virtual machine, but since the license of OS X v10.6 (non-server version) doesn't allow virtualization...